# Connecting Java , C++ and PHP to each other

Tags: java, php, c++, java-native-interface

I want to code my web-service in java....but what if i can write my main code in c++ & then access via JNI to use in java and is it efficient or not ?
Secondly , I have to create a website and again that c++ code will be used to fetch data but website will be in php..is that possible...& how ?

Please also suggest me if I am going wrong...? or Some other way to do this thing...!

[image: implementation diagram]

this is the implementation diagram...is it possible & also efficient or not..?

Comment: first thing that comes to my mind... WHY JUST WHYYYY. There should be nothing, you can't program in java what you could in c++ (speaking of web services). Same for PHP -> C++... either you can fetch the required data for your website easily, or think about another aproach to your website...

Comment: show the code what you tried? then only others can help easily.

Comment: IMHO, Code web service (C++ **or** Java) then consume it on your web site (PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this possible? Yes.

Is this efficient? Arguable, but I would say no.

I would suggest that your best bet is to use only one language for your web application. All three of C++, Java, and PHP have great web service capabilities. If you have to add so many layers of technology, managing your application will quickly become a nightmare.

**EDIT**

Since you are creating a web service for an Android app, I would advise that you write it in Java. This is because you can take advantage of code reuse, and is also helpful if you want to add developers to your team.

PHP and C++ are good choices as well. I personally prefer PHP in this scenario, due to the simplicity of setup. I would only choose C++ over PHP if I had some previous code that is reusable, so I do not need to port over any business logic.

From there, you can use build an Android application to talk to your web service, as well as create the front end for your website.

Answer (score 0):

I know that does not exactly answers your question... But why wouldn't you write everything in one language C++.

You can create both web services and web sites in C++ as easily as in Java or PHP using good web framework like: [CppCMS](http://cppcms.com)

Making combinations of 3 different technologies, writing numerous wrappers would make your life much harder.

Comment: my aim is to create a web-service and then to consume it..into my website and to android apps...i want best approach..performance & portability wise
What approch shud i follow...suggest me..i am confused

Comment: @BehindDWalls ^this explanation is a lot more clear than your original question.

Comment: @BehindDWalls I'd suggest to split it. Web application and Android applications are **VERY** different. So the idea of reuse the code would likely fail to some marginal cases. So for server side use one language, for andriod, other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding your "Main Implementation" from scratch then why you are doing it in C++ ? do you have any library dependency which is only available in C++ ? or do you have a lot of your works already done in C++ for Main Implementation ?

Otherwise why you are using three different languages for these purpose ? you can do all 3 of them in one single language which may be any of Java, PHP or C++

You can always make your C++ library a DLL and even export that as a PHP module. but why take that additional overhead if you can manage all your work in PHP or in JAVA. and on a sidenote just using C++ will not give you added performance benefit. you need to change your structures and algorithms to get a performance benefit.

having 3 languages for three different part of your application will be less manageable as compared to having a single language for everything. I've seen many people getting messed up by doing this fascination. you may face less work more workarounds latter.

You can CppCMS or Wt or pion If you want to run Web services or even Website in C++ but while doing web thing you have to be very careful for memory leaks because one small memory leak can bloat your server. and you don't need have that overhead while using JAVA or PHP.